# Оформление кода

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как правильно располагать элементы кода? Например, все объявления переменных вверху, потом функции и тд.

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript например пункт 13.4

Comment: Если вопрос от новичка, https://learn.javascript.ru/ — 3-й пункт дает базовые простые правила. Когда узнаешь, что такое классы, ООП, и сам начнешь путаться в своем же коде, `Макконнелл - Совершенный код` 800 страниц, но практически без воды, куча полезных советов.

Comment: Я уже знаю, что такое классы, ООП, правда ничего сложного не делал, чтобы путаться. Спасибо за совет :)

Answer (score 1):

В этом вопросе нет единой нормы, это стиль кода и вариантов может быть много. Если нет синтаксических ошибок и программа работает правильно, значит минимум правильности соблюдён. Другое дело, что стиль оформления влияет на читабельность кода, вероятность возникновения ошибок, лёгкость сопровождения и т.п. Поэтому существует потенциально неограниченное количество стилистических систем, полезных советов, принципов — от основополагающих до касающихся мельчайших деталей.

Вы можете просмотреть несколько популярных стилистических систем для начала. Например:

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html

Чтобы эти принципы было легче применять на практике, существуют линтеры кода, проверяющие как его структуру, так и формальные мелочи. Одни из самых известных на сегодня — вот эта взаимодополняющая пара:

https://eslint.org/

https://prettier.io/